# Why does setting an optionsValue break Knockout updating?

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I've been going through the Knockout tutorials, and I was playing around with one tutorial when something puzzled me.  Here is my HTML:

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, optionsValue: 'mealVal', optionsText: 'mealName', value: meal"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

... and here is my JavaScript:

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        var price = self.meal().price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";        
    });
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealVal: "STD", mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealVal: "PRM", mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealVal: "ULT", mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);

    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

When I run this example and select a different "Meal" from the dropdown menu for a passenger, the "Surcharge" value is **not** updated.  The reason for this seems to be that I added `optionsValue: 'mealVal'` into the `data-bind` attribute for the `select`, and when I remove that, the "Surcharge" does indeed update when a new dropdown option is selected.  But why does adding `optionsValue` break the updating?  All that does is set the `select` list's option `value` attributes, which is quite useful for form submission - I don't see why it should prevent Knockout from auto-updating.

**UPDATE:** Upon further investigation, I've discovered that the `formattedPrice` fn is still getting called, but `self.meal()` is now resolving to the value string such as `PRM` instead of the whole meal object.  But why is this?  The documentation says that `optionsValue` sets the `value` attribute in the HTML, but doesn't say anything about changing the view model behaviour.

I think what's going on is that when you specify `options: $root.availableMeals`, but don't specify an `optionsValue`, Knockout magically determines which selection in the list you've made when the selection is changed and gives you access to the *object* from `availableMeals` instead of just the string value that was put into the `value` attribute.  This does not appear to be well-documented.

Comment: There's a short paragraph explaining `optionsValue` in the documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#parameters). "Typically you’d only want to use optionsValue as a way of ensuring that KO can correctly retain selection when you update the set of available options." If your own update answers your question, I'd suggest posting it as an answer. If you've any questions left, please let me/us know what remains unclear.

Comment: That's still unclear because it doesn't explain why, when you set `optionsValue`, the `formattedPrice` function goes from getting the whole meal object passed in to just the `optionsValue` value.  Why doesn't it continue getting the whole meal object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after looking through the Knockout code, I've figured out what's happening - and as of the time of writing this is not documented.

The `value` binding, when it reads the value of a `select` element, doesn't just look at the DOM value for the element; [it calls `var elementValue = ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element);`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/9893233413e467a40919237e524b545e335c1050/src/binding/defaultBindings/value.js#L85)

Now, what `selectExtensions` does, unsurprisingly, is implement special behaviour for `select` (and their child `object`) elements.  This is where the magic happens, because as the comment in the code says:

```
    // Normally, SELECT elements and their OPTIONs can only take value of type 'string' (because the values
    // are stored on DOM attributes). ko.selectExtensions provides a way for SELECTs/OPTIONs to have values
    // that are arbitrary objects. This is very convenient when implementing things like cascading dropdowns.
```

So, when the value binding tries to read the `select` element [via `selectExtensions.readValue(...)`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/9893233413e467a40919237e524b545e335c1050/src/binding/selectExtensions.js#L8), it will come to this code:

```
        case 'select':
            return element.selectedIndex >= 0 ? ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element.options[element.selectedIndex]) : undefined;
```

This basically says "OK, find the selected index and use this function again to read the `option` element at that index.  So then it reads the `option` element and comes to this:

```
        case 'option':
            if (element[hasDomDataExpandoProperty] === true)
                return ko.utils.domData.get(element, ko.bindingHandlers.options.optionValueDomDataKey);
            return ko.utils.ieVersion <= 7
                ? (element.getAttributeNode('value') && element.getAttributeNode('value').specified ? element.value : element.text)
                : element.value;
```

Aha!  So it stores its own "has DOM data expando property" flag and if that is set it DOESN'T get the simple `element.value`, but it goes to its own JavaScript memory and gets the value.  This is how it can return a complex JS object (like the meal object in my question's example) instead of just the `value` attribute string.  However, if that flag is not set, it does indeed just return the `value` attribute string.

The `writeValue` extension, predictably, has the other side of this where it will write the complex data to JS memory if it's not a string, but otherwise it will just store it in the `value` attribute string for the `option`:

```
    switch (ko.utils.tagNameLower(element)) {
        case 'option':
            if (typeof value === "string") {
                ko.utils.domData.set(element, ko.bindingHandlers.options.optionValueDomDataKey, undefined);
                if (hasDomDataExpandoProperty in element) { // IE <= 8 throws errors if you delete non-existent properties from a DOM node
                    delete element[hasDomDataExpandoProperty];
                }
                element.value = value;
            }
            else {
                // Store arbitrary object using DomData
                ko.utils.domData.set(element, ko.bindingHandlers.options.optionValueDomDataKey, value);
                element[hasDomDataExpandoProperty] = true;

                // Special treatment of numbers is just for backward compatibility. KO 1.2.1 wrote numerical values to element.value.
                element.value = typeof value === "number" ? value : "";
            }
            break;
```

So yeah, as I suspected, Knockout is storing complex data behind-the-scenes but only when you ask it to store a complex JS object.  This explains why, when you don't specify `optionsValue: [someStringValue]`, your computed function received the complex meal object, whereas when you do specify it, you just get the basic string passed in - Knockout is just giving you the string from the `option`'s `value` attribute.

Personally I think this should be CLEARLY documented because it is a bit unexpected and special behaviour that is potentially confusing, even if it's convenient.  I'll be asking them to add it to the documentation.

Comment: Glad to see you dug deep in to the source and figured out the exact behavior! Personally, I'd love to see `optionsValue` be *replaced* by an `optionsEqualityComparer` binding: pass a function of `(a, b) -> boolean` that is used to match the `value` to an element of `options`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you understand what's happening and why it breaks your code, but are still looking for an explanation on when you actually need to use `optionsValue`, and when not.

## When to use the `optionsValue` binding

Let's say your meals can be sold out and you want to check with the server for updates in `availableMeals`:

```js
const availableMeals = ko.observableArray([]);
const loadMeals = () => getMeals().then(availableMeals);
const selectedMeal = ko.observable(null);

loadMeals();

ko.applyBindings({ loadMeals, availableMeals, selectedMeal });

function getMeals() {
  return {
    then: function(cb) {
      setTimeout(cb.bind(null, [{ mealVal: "STD", mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 }, { mealVal: "PRM", mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 }, { mealVal: "ULT", mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }]), 500);  
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: availableMeals, 
                   value: selectedMeal,
                   optionsText: 'mealName'"></select>
                   
<button data-bind="click: loadMeals">refresh meals</button>

<div data-bind="with: selectedMeal">
  You've selected <em data-bind="text: mealName"></em>
</div>

<div data-bind="ifnot: selectedMeal">No selection</div>

<p>Make a selection, click on refresh and notice the selection is lost when new data arrives.</p>
```

What happens when you replace the objects in `availableMeals`:

- Knockout re-renders the select box's options
- Knockout checks the new values for `selectedMeal() === mealObject`
- Knockout does not find the object in `selectedMeal` and defaults to the first option
- Knockout writes the new object's reference to `selectedMeal`

**Problem: you loose your UI selection because the object it points to is no longer in the available options.**

### `optionsValue` to the rescue!

The `optionsValue` allows us to solve this issue. Instead of storing a reference to an *object* that might be replaced at any time, we store a *primitive* value, the string inside `mealVal`, that allows us to check for equality in between different API calls! Knockout now does something like:

```
selection = newObjects.find(o => o["mealVal"] === selectedMeal());
```

Let's see this in action:

```js
const availableMeals = ko.observableArray([]);
const loadMeals = () => getMeals().then(availableMeals);
const selectedMeal = ko.observable(null);

loadMeals();

ko.applyBindings({ loadMeals, availableMeals, selectedMeal });

function getMeals() {
  return {
    then: function(cb) {
      setTimeout(cb.bind(null, [{ mealVal: "STD", mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 }, { mealVal: "PRM", mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 }, { mealVal: "ULT", mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }]), 500);  
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: availableMeals, 
                   value: selectedMeal,
                   optionsText: 'mealName',
                   optionsValue: 'mealVal'"></select>
                   
<button data-bind="click: loadMeals">refresh meals</button>

<div data-bind="if: selectedMeal">
  You've selected <em data-bind="text: selectedMeal"></em>
</div>

<div data-bind="ifnot: selectedMeal">No selection</div>

<p>Make a selection, click on refresh and notice the selection is lost when new data arrives.</p>
```

### The downsides of `optionsValue`

Notice how I had to rewrite the `with` binding? Suddenly, we only have one of `meal`'s properties available in our viewmodel, which is quite limiting. Here's where you'll have to do some additional work if you want your app to be able to update its data. Your two options:

1. Store the string (hash) of your selection *and* the actual object independently, or
2. Have a repository of view models, when new server data arrives, map to the existing instances to ensure you keep selection states.

<sub>If it helps, I could add code snippets to explain those two approaches a bit better</sub>

Comment: I don't see where you rewrote the `with` binding?  And, yes, adding code snippets would indeed help.